# How to manage navigation stack in swiftUI?

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

I am new to learning in swiftUI, I have to manage following navigation stack in SwiftUI,

**Here is my first entry of the app :-**

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct MyApp: App {
  var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
      Landing()
    }
  }
}
```

**here is the Landing Page :-**

```
struct Landing: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            HStack(spacing: 13) {
                NavigationLink {
                    Login()
                } label: {
                    DetezoMainNavigationBtn(title: LandingScreenTexts.logIn)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**here is my Login Page :-**

```
struct Login: View {
    @State var isSignInClicked = false
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            
            DetezoMainButton(title: LoginScreenTexts.logIn, acttion:         {
                isSignInClicked = true
            })
            
        }
        .navigationDestination(isPresented: $isSignInClicked, destination: {
            MyZone()
        })
    }
}
```

Okay here is my minimal requirement is when I click login from Landing Page then swipe to back gesture and navigation back should work.
But when I click on Login button on login page then swipe to back gesture and navigation back should not work. And navigation Stack should reset and MyZone page should be the new parent of navigation stack

Comment: Can you [create a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @son I have edited with minimal example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a second `NavigationStack` in your `Login` view. This screen is pushed onto the stack that is in your `Landing` view.

Just remove that and it should work fine.

A better way to write this might be to remove the nav stack from your `Landing` screen…

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct MyApp: App {
  var body: some Scene {

    @State var isLoggedIn = false

    WindowGroup {
      if isLoggedIn {
        NavigationStack {
          MainScreen()
        }
      } else {
        NavigationStack {
          Landing()
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

struct Landing: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 13) {
            NavigationLink {
                Login()
            } label: {
                DetezoMainNavigationBtn(title: LandingScreenTexts.logIn)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Login: View {
// etc
}
```

Comment: Ashley Thanks,
From login I have to navigate user to Dashboard screen after logged in successfully . 
In that case I have to reset navigation stack so that user can't swipe left to back to previous screen

Comment: You could handle this by having two independent flows for logged in / out users (see my update above). You could update the isLoggedIn state by, for example, passing it as a binding to the sign in view

Comment: How could I bind the isLoggedIn to the Login view can you please give me the example.
I mean how can I update "isLoggedIn" state from Login View ?

Comment: There is Apple documentation, blog posts, and plenty of questions on SO on how to pass a state variable as a binding. If, after doing some more research, it's not clear how that works, ask another question.

Answer (score 1):

This solution meets all your needs. You don't need to add NavigationStack to subviews.

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct MyApp: App {
    @State var isSignInClicked = false
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            if isSignInClicked {
                MyZone()
            } else {
                Landing(isSignInClicked: $isSignInClicked)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Landing: View {
    @Binding var isSignInClicked: Bool
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            HStack(spacing: 13) {
                NavigationLink {
                    Login(isSignInClicked: $isSignInClicked)
                } label: {
                    Text("Landing Screen Log In")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Login: View {
    @Binding var isSignInClicked: Bool
    var body: some View {
        Button("Log in") {
            isSignInClicked = true
        }
    }
}

struct MyZone: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack{
            VStack {
                Text("My Zone Code")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you only want to use NavigationLink to jump to other views, add the .navigationBarBackButtonHidden() modifier to the view that you don't want the navigation back button. This solution doesn't reset NavigationStack but works fine for your minimal requirement:

```
//From the landing page, no need to change
struct Landing: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            HStack(spacing: 13) {
                NavigationLink {
                    Login()
                } label: {
                    Text("Landing Screen Log In")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

//From the Login page, add the modifier and hide the back button of the destination view
struct Login: View {
    @State var isSignInClicked = false
    var body: some View {
        Button("Log in") {
            isSignInClicked = true
        }
        .navigationDestination(isPresented: $isSignInClicked, destination: {MyZone().navigationBarBackButtonHidden()})
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can add the modifier to your MyZone() page

```
struct MyZone: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("My Zone")
        }
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden()
    }
}
```

Just so you know, on your Login page, you made a syntax error.
The .navigationDestination should be inside the NavigationStack.

```
NavigationStack {
    Button() 
        .navigationDestination()
}
```